# Handle 2 buttons in single form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 buttons and 2 actions in controller, on one button click I need to handle one action, another button click I need to handle another action, how can I achieve this

I gave different values and same names

```
<input type="Submit" class="button" value="Search" name="btnName" />

<input type="Submit" class="button" value="Save" name="btnName" />
```

Comment: If you can use JavaScript you can react to the onclick event of each button and use JavaScript to submit to the desired action for a given button.

Comment: Do you have POST actions or GET?

Comment: I USED HTTPPOST FOR BOTH THE ACTIONS, IM SORRY IM JUST A BEGINNER TO MVC, I CAN USE JAVASCRIPT ALSO

Comment: shall i post my action methods or any code?

Comment: Dont use the same names for your buttons, each button must have it own unique name

Comment: <input type="Submit" class="button" value="Search" name="btnName" />,<input type="Submit" class="button" value="Save" name="btnName" />

Comment: opk after giving unique names?

Comment: whats is your controller and action names

Comment: controller name manageroles, action name manageroles

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Html.Action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "NameOfAction", "NameOfController")
```

here is an ajax link

```
    Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Save",
        "NameOfAction",
        "NameOfController",
        new { id = "AnyIdIfNeeded" },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            OnFailure = "JavascriptThatHandlesFailed",
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "SomeDivIdToUpdate",
            LoadingElementId = "IdOfDivThatShowsLoading",
            OnSuccess = "JavascriptMethodThatHandlesSuccess"
        }
        ).ToHtmlString());
```

A simple form

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ManageRoles", "ManageRoles", FormMethod.POST, new { id = "SearchForm" }))
{
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit();">Save</a>
}
```

Comment: <input type="Submit" class="button" value="Save" name="btnName" />
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "ManageRoles", "ManageRoles")

Comment: How would an actionLink post the form back to the server?

Comment: i pasted in before my save button

Comment: that's not working, i got a hyper link beside my save button and when i click that hyperlink also nothing is happening, i don't need hyperlink there

Comment: You can change GET to POST if needed

Comment: do i need to make any changes to the code above, ajax link and the below code?

Comment: So your Action and controller names are both ManageRoles ?

Comment: yes both are manageroles, but i have 2 actions in controller, one is manageroles and the other is managedeals, anyway 1st im trying to handle manageroles